# Converting list of points to list of tuples in python

Tags: python

I've just written some code to convert a list of points into a list of to/from tuples but it doesn't feel very efficient.

I was wondering if anyone had any suggestions to make this more concise?

```
from_point, to_point = None, None
point_list = []

for p in [1, 5, 2, 4, 7, 9]:
    to_point = p
    if from_point and to_point:
        point_list.append((from_point, to_point))
    from_point = to_point

print(point_list)
```

Input: `[1, 5, 2, 4, 7, 9]`

Output: `[(1, 5), (5, 2), (2, 4), (4, 7), (7, 9)]`

Edit: Changed points to be non sequential.

Comment: Why do you test `if from_point and to_point`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem To make sure I have valid to/from points before appending to the point_list. Without this the first point would be (None, 5)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
>>> p = [1, 5, 2, 4, 7, 9]
>>> point_list = list(zip(p[:-1], p[1:]))
>>> print(point_list)
[(1, 5), (5, 2), (2, 4), (4, 7), (7, 9)]
```

Comment: Oh, that's tight! Thanks!

Comment: Since we care about efficiency, perhaps using `itertools.islice` instead of list slices would be best.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative one line solution

```
input = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
output = [(input[index], input[index+1]) for index in range(len(list)-1)]
print(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
x=[1, 5, 2, 4, 7, 9]
print [ tuple(x[i:i+2]) for i in xrange(len(x)-1) ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [`more_itertools`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#more_itertools.pairwise):

```
import more_itertools as mit

list(mit.pairwise([1, 5, 2, 4, 7, 9]))
# [(1, 5), (5, 2), (2, 4), (4, 7), (7, 9)]
```